Does have subgather command like subequation? (elsevier format) (I wanna 1a,1b,1c)
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
    \sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 {{{\bar d}_i}{c_i}^3 = \frac{1}{{12}}},\label{eq Sixth order u 1}\\
    \sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^{i - 1} {{{\bar d}_i}{\bar A_{ij}}} } \right)}  = \frac{1}{{72}},\label{eq Sixth order u 2}\\
    \sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 {\left( {\sum\limits_{j = 2}^{i - 1} {{{\bar d}_i}{\bar A_{ij}}{c_j}} } \right)}  = \frac{1}{{72}}.
    \label{eq Sixth order u 3}
\end{gather}
\end{document}



don't use subequation command can get the goal?

a screenshot of just the output would be more useful than an image of code. (I appreciate you've also provided the code, which is great, but an image of the code doesn't add much. on the other hand, the output is very small, whereas all the extraneous bits of the image are much more visible/distracting.)

Welcome to TeX.SE. There is no \subgather command. There is an environment (not a command) called subequations -- note the plural form.

@cfr, Thanks for your advice!

@Mico, thanks for your advice!

how to reply to certain person? my way to use @ is right? i am the new user in this website

@Aixleftmath yes, that's right. the site will complete the user name for you if you're doing it right. note you can only respond to one person per comment. but I could have responded to, say, Mico here and you'd still have been pinged, too, because this is a comment on your question.

You need to encase the gather environment in a subequations environment in order to change the numbering system of the equations in question from (1)-(2)-(3) to (1a)-(1b)-(1c)
Three additional comments: (i) Your code contains an impressive amount of unnecessary pairs of curly braces. While this is ultimately harmless, in the sense that TeX ignores the surplus TeX groups, it does make debugging and updating such code by a human rather tedious and prone to mistakes. (ii) Since the code is processed in display-style math mode inside a gather environment, the \limits qualifiers are redundant. (iii) As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, it would be a really good idea to replace all instances of {\bar <x>} with \bar{<x>}, where <x> would be either A or d in the code at hand.
In short, I hope you will agree that
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \bar{d}_i c_i^3 = \frac{1}{12}

is easier to read, debug and maintain than
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^3 {{{\bar d}_i}{c_i}^3 = \frac{1}{{12}}}

is.

\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{%amsmath, % 'amsmath' is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
            amssymb,
            %amsfonts, % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
            amsthm,
            mathtools}
   
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{gather}
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \bar{d}_i c_i^3 = \frac{1}{12}\,,
    \label{eq Sixth order u 1}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \biggl( \sum_{j = 1}^{i - 1} \bar{d}_i \bar{A}_{ij} \biggr) = \frac{1}{72}\,,
    \label{eq Sixth order u 2}\\
\sum_{i = 1}^3 \biggl( \sum_{j = 2}^{i - 1} \bar{d}_i \bar{A}_{ij} c_j \biggr) = \frac{1}{72}\,.
    \label{eq Sixth order u 3}
\end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}


Also \bar d should be discouraged in favor of \bar{d}

@egreg - Thanks for this. I've added your point to the list of "additional comments" in my answer given above.

Really appreciate your help and answer! it does help me a lot!

@Mico, thanks for your advice on the math equation type! cause I use mathtype and copy it in the latex editor (it transfer to the code auto), so maybe lead to some redundant code? (but it still can compile)

@Aixleftmath - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with mathtype.
